# How to pass one variable in every route by default?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain

I am working with wildcard sub domain.And i have defined route and its name like

```
Route::group(['domain'=>'{subdomain}.'.config('app.url')], function(){
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'Dashboard', ['as'=>'school']);
});
```

While redirecting it using route name `redirect(route('school.dashboard.index'))` it says `Missing required parameters for...`  if i pass variable same route name like`redirect(route('school.dashboard.index', 'subdomainname'))` it works perfect. Here i have to pass `subdomain` in each and every redirect using route name. What i want to do is, i want to pass that variable by default in every route name. How can i do this?

Comment: set another variable in config file for subdomain like `config('app.url')`

Answer (score 1):

In methods of `DashboardController`, you need to do something like this:

```
public function index($subdomain)
```

Instead of just:

```
public function index()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

And when you're using helpers like `route()` to create links, pass subdomain too:

```
redirect(route('school.dashboard.index', ['subdomain' => $subdomain]))
```